# Destructuring key, value, and index of an object in es6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Can you destructure the key, value, and index of an object in a forEach?

I understand destructuring key and value would look like:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  ...
});
```

But I'm hoping to also destructure the index.

My attempt:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach((entry, index) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    ...
});
```

But wasn't sure if there was a better way. I know this is a pretty basic question but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just list the index argument normally after destructuring the first argument:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
```

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'val'
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
  console.log(key, value, index);
});
```

Comment: Duh. Thank you! Will mark this as the correct answer when SO lets me in 12 mins :)